# Googlemap autocomplete not working even with working code

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

i have found some codes for auto complete and it works, like this

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>

function initialize() {

        var input = document.getElementById('address');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

<input id="address" type="text" size="50"/>
```

this works perfectly in a project just for auto complete.

but when i implement this in my actual project, it doesn't work,i am not sure where to put those codes.

this is my full project code.everything works fine but the auto complete is not working

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS.css"/>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAfJKrk9pQNoNTIGTzj6f0jLXL78ryRnxQ&sensor=false"> 

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/output?parameters"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3&libraries=geometry"></script>
    <script>

        var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(3.213912, 101.727202); /
        var newmarker; //global variable to set new marker
        var map;
        var newlat;
        var newlng;
        var newmarkerpos;
        var rendererOptions = {
            draggable: true 
        };
        var start;
        var end;
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        //var infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        //    content: '<div id="infowindow1" style="CSS.css"></div>'
        //});

        function initialize() {

            var input = document.getElementById('address');
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

            var mapProperty = {
                center: myCenter,                            
                zoom: 17,                                   
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 
                scaleControl: true,                         
                overviewMapControl: true           
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap")
              , mapProperty);

            var input = document.getElementById('address');
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: '<div id="infowindow" style="CSS.css">We are here!</div>'
            });


            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myCenter,                     
                animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE, 
                icon: '../Images/Icon4.png'
            });

            marker.setMap(map);

            directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directionspanel'));


            infowindow.open(map, marker);

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                map.setZoom(17);
                map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
            });

            function placeMarker(location) {

                if (newmarker) {
                    newmarker.setPosition(location);
                    newmarker.setVisible(true);
                } else {
                    newmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: location,
                        map: map,
                        icon: '../Images/Icon4.png',
                        //draggable: true,
                    });

                }

                newlat = location.lat();    
                newlng = location.lng();

                newmarkerpos = new google.maps.LatLng(newlat, newlng);


            }


            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
                placeMarker(event.latLng);
            }); 

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(home, 'click', function () {
                map.setZoom(17);
                map.setCenter(myCenter)
            });

        }

        function cal() {

            start = new google.maps.LatLng(3.213912, 101.727202);
            end = new google.maps.LatLng(newmarkerpos.lat(), newmarkerpos.lng());
            var request = {

                origin: start,
                destination: end,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            };
            directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                }
            });
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            newmarker.setVisible(false);

        }

        function clearmap() {

            newmarker.setVisible(false);
            newmarkerpos = null;
            directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
            document.getElementById("directionspanel").innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById('address').value = "";

        }

        function geocode() {
            var address = document.getElementById('address').value;

            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var geolat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    var geolng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

                    start = new google.maps.LatLng(3.213912, 101.727202);
                    end = new google.maps.LatLng(geolat, geolng);
                    var request = {

                        origin: start,
                        destination: end,
                        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
                    };
                    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                        }
                    });
                    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
                    newmarker.setMap(null);

                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                    newmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: results[0].geometry.location,
                        map: map,
                        zoom: 15,
                        icon: '../Images/Icon4.png',
                        draggable: true,

                    });


                }
            });

        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); 
    </script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Our Location</h1>
    <div id="googleMap" style="width:800px; height:450px;">
    </div> 
<!--    <div id="dvdistance" style="width:400px; height:100px; border:solid">
    see ///***
    </div>-->
    <div id="geocoding">
        <input id="address" type="text" placeholder="Enter an address" size="33" />
        <input type="button" value="geocode" onclick="geocode()" />
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="home" style:"CSS.css" >HOME</button>
    <button type="button" id="clearmap" onclick="clearmap()" style:"CSS.css">CLEAR MAP</button>
    <input type="button" id="cal" onclick="cal()" value="GET DIRECTION" />
    <div id="directionspanel" style:"CSS.css"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

i have placed the auto complete after i set up my map.
but now the auto complete is not working.
what's the problem?
Where should i place it?

Comment: Please provide enough code to replicate the problem. http://sscce.org/

Comment: is there any specified place where should i place my code for the autocomplete?

Comment: No there isn't (with caveats that the DOM has to be rendered before you try to access it).  You didn't provide any of the HTML.

Comment: i have changed edited, take a look

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. It is the script.

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAfJKrk9pQNoNTIGTzj6f0jLXL78ryRnxQ&sensor=false"> <!--key is registred at google console-->

</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
```

i have deleted all other scripts and left only these 2. Surprisingly it works and i still have no idea why. And all my other functions work well too.